# skip rule creation if parameter is empty in Azure Storage life cycle management

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to skip creation of **Delete Rule** if the parameter that is supplied by the parameter.json file is empty in ARM Template. How this can be achieve?

```
      "rules": [
                {
                  "name": "ruleDefault",
                  "enabled": true,
                  "type": "Lifecycle",
                  "definition": {
                    "filters": {
                      "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ],
                      "prefixMatch": [ "container1/foo" ]
                    },
                    "actions": {
                      "baseBlob": {
                        "tierToCool": {
                          "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": "[parameters('tierToCool')]"
                        },
                        "tierToArchive": {
                          "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": "[parameters('tierToArchive')]"                      
                        },                    
                        "delete": {
                          "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": "[parameters('delete')]"
                        }
                      },
                      "snapshot": {
                        "delete": { "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": "[parameters('snapshot')]" }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of conditional logic.

The first and most common is the `condition` key. This key sits within a resource block which is supplied a value that can be evaluated to true or false. **If the condition is met, the resource will be created. If it is not, then it will be skipped**.

```
"condition": "[not(empty(parameters('delete')))]"
```

The second is called inline conditional logic, which is very powerful and has a simple to use syntax:

```
[if(condition, true value, false value)]
```

Inline logic is used outside of the condition key. The inline logic will check to see **if the “delete” parameter is empty, if it is then it sets the json to null, which basically ignores the value.** If the “delte” parameter is not empty, it will assign the rule to the `daysAfterModificationGreaterThan`.

```
"daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": "[if(equals(parameters('delete'), ''), json('null'),parameters('delete'))]"
```

For more details you could refer to this article about [ARM Template – Conditional Logic](http://www.inthecloud.net/arm-template-conditional-logic/) and this [one](https://azurecitadel.com/automation/arm/lab4/).